# Not able to fix "PHP Notice: Undefined variable" and "Undefined index" in code

Tags: php

I have been running a Web App for quite some time. The app works even after multiple PHP errors but the error log files are constantly taking 1 GB of my space after every few weeks forcing me to manually delete them. The error resides in a faucet.php file

I am not familiar with Php, I have done everything I can to tackle this error and even check the similar questions but none of it prove to be a fixture of my problem.

These are four error messages and keeps repeating throughout the day.

```
Undefined variable

PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: refer_file in /home/countnet/public_html/faucet/network/mine/doge/faucet.php on **line 318**

PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: refer_file in /home/countnet/public_html/faucet/network/mine/doge/faucet.php on **line 393**

And Undefined index

PHP Notice:  Undefined index: status in /home/countnet/public_html/faucet/network/mine/doge/faucet.php on **line 604**

PHP Notice:  Undefined index: status in /home/countnet/public_html/faucet/network/mine/doge/faucet.php on **line 608**



**Line 318**     if (!$refer_file) {

**Line 393**     if (!$refer_file) { // the user was referred and the referral isn't saved 

**Line 604**     echo '\'status\': \'' . htmlspecialchars($result['status'], ENT_QUOTES|ENT_SUBSTITUTE|ENT_DISALLOWED|ENT_HTML5) . '\',';

**Line 608**

echo '<dl><dt>Status</dt><dd>' . htmlspecialchars($result['status'], ENT_QUOTES|ENT_SUBSTITUTE|ENT_DISALLOWED|ENT_HTML5) . '</dd><dt>Message</dt><dd>' . htmlspecialchars($result['message'], ENT_QUOTES|ENT_SUBSTITUTE|ENT_DISALLOWED|ENT_HTML5) . '</dd></dl>';
```

Any help would be appreciated, the app works fine even with these errors but they are now becoming a nightmare as traffic grows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use [isset()](https://www.php.net/isset) or [empty()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) to check if the variable or array index are defined or not.

Line 318 and 393 can be changed to

```
if (!empty($refer_file)) {
```

for line 604 and 608 add something like the following before line 604:

```
$result['status'] = isset($result['status']) ? $result['status'] : 'default_status';
$result['message'] = isset($result['message']) ? $result['message'] : 'default_message';
```

Comment: Thanks, it got fixed no more frustration after months =)

Comment: You are welcome. If this answer helped you fixing your issue. Would you please  mark as the right answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use isset to check whether the variable/index of array exist or not.

```
if (isset($refer_file)) {

    if (!$refer_file) { // the user was referred and the referral isn't saved 
    if(isset($result['status']) && isset($result['message'])){
        echo '\'status\': \'' . htmlspecialchars($result['status'], ENT_QUOTES|ENT_SUBSTITUTE|ENT_DISALLOWED|ENT_HTML5) . '\',';}
        echo '<dl><dt>Status</dt><dd>' . htmlspecialchars($result['status'], ENT_QUOTES|ENT_SUBSTITUTE|ENT_DISALLOWED|ENT_HTML5) . '</dd><dt>Message</dt><dd>' . htmlspecialchars($result['message'], ENT_QUOTES|ENT_SUBSTITUTE|ENT_DISALLOWED|ENT_HTML5) . '</dd></dl>';
    }
```